# Issue with CMake project building

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, cmake

I have the following problem. On my Ubuntu I try to build a project and receive the following linker error(s) so far:

```
/usr/bin/ld:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.a(once.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_once@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO
missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [sunprint] Error 1 make[1]: ***
[CMakeFiles/sunprint.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Failure: Exit code 2 ***
```

I'm running under ubuntu 13 desktop, GCC 4.8, boost ver. is 1.54. As an IDE I'm working with 
is the KDevelop.
I can provide any additional info about this issue if needed, but now I'm stuck with 
this linking problem.

Any ideas?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`add_definitions` only adds inputs for the preprocessor, which is in action even before the *compiler* starts its business and even much farther away from linking the executable, the step `ld` is supposed to be doing.

What you want to have `ld` resolve link-time dependencies is the CMake command `target_link_libraries`, which, for a given target, add a number of libs to link against after compilation.

In you case, the appropriate invocation could look like this

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} [...] -lpthread [...]) #obviously without the '[...]' and the correct target name
```

Comment: Thank you!. This made the project build w\o any other questions :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but with `mpich`. Both:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} [...] -lmpich [...])
```

and

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} [...] mpich [...])
```

worked properly.